# Qual a hora certa para incluir plugins em um programa?

Tags: plugin, projeto-de-software

Estive acompanhando vários projetos de código aberto e percebi que vários deles possuem suporte a `plugins`. Surgem algumas dúvidas:

1. Qual a melhor hora para adicionar `plugins`? Devo me preocupar com eles desde o projeto do sistema, ou devo deixar eles para um momento mais oportuno?
2. Todos os problemas podem ser resolvidos com `plugins`? Qual a finalidade de um `plugin`?
3. Aparentemente muitos projetos veem os `plugins` como as funcionalidades básicas de seus sistemas, quando em meu entendimento, os plugins deveriam ser apenas funcionalidades "extras". Meu pensamento está coerente?
4. Para o caso de eu resolver adicionar `plugins` a um aplicativo, existe alguma metodologia pronta para que eu possa me basear e evite cometer erros de design?
5. Vamos imaginar que eu esteja desenvolvendo um sistema X e que no momento da concepção do projeto eu tenho apenas suporte para uma biblioteca A. Se eu desejar futuramente adicionar um backend para uma biblioteca B de funcionalidade semelhante, qual a melhor forma de resolver isto? Os plugins podem ajudar a resolver este problema?

Comment: Embora essa pergunta dê certa margem para opiniões, acho ela muito interessante e "respondível", de modo que estou votando por deixá-la aberta.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Acho que tens razão, se levar em consideração esta parte da pergunta *Devo me preocupar com eles desde o projeto do sistema, ou devo deixar eles para um momento mais oportuno?* Se você tiver uma resposta para o colega então irei votar para reabrir também.

Answer (score 1):

> Qual a melhor hora para adicionar plugins?

Se você prevê que certas funcionalidades são interessantes para seu sistema, mas que ficariam melhor fora do seu "núcleo", então ajuda projetá-lo desde o início de modo a esperar plugins.

Um exemplo seria um programa que trata de diversos formatos de arquivo, mas não quer ficar "amarrado" com os formatos nativamente suportados. Nesse caso, é melhor abstrair o tratamento desses arquivos, e escrever um plugin para cada formato desejado. Facilitando, é claro, o desenvolvimento e a implantação de novos plugins, inclusive por terceiros.

> Qual a finalidade de um plugin?

Um plugin é um **complemento** para seu sistema, uma forma de estender as funcionalidades básicas do mesmo. Dessa forma, um plugin só faz aquilo que o sistema "deixa" ele fazer, não dá pra resolver *qualquer* problema possível e imaginário dessa forma (a menos que o "plugin" use *monkey patch* ou mesmo modifique os fontes do sistema original e os recompile - caso em que ele é mais chamado de *"mod"* que de *"plugin"*).

Há quem tente projetar sistemas inteiros como uma pequena fundação genérica e um grande conjunto de plugins. Esse tipo de arquitetura é complicada, pois é preciso gerenciar com cuidado as dependências entre os plugins, mas o resultado final é um sistema com maior flexibilidade. *A princípio* poderia-se substituir qualquer plugin por outro de modo a alterar a funcionalidade do sistema, mas na prática a cadeia de dependências torna difícil modificar a "base" do sistema, de modo que mesmo esse modelo possui limitações.

> Aparentemente muitos projetos veem os plugins como as funcionalidades básicas de seus sistemas, quando em meu entendimento, os plugins deveriam ser apenas funcionalidades "extras".

Não necessariamente, veja o primeiro exemplo dos formatos de arquivo, aquilo pode ser uma funcionalidade "básica" (i.e. você precisa de no mínimo 1 tipo de arquivo suportado pro sistema fazer qualquer coisa de útil) mas ainda ser melhor modelada na forma de plugins. O ponto chave é identificar que áreas do sistema demandam alta customização, e se preparar para atendê-las de acordo.

> Para o caso de eu resolver adicionar plugins a um aplicativo, existe alguma metodologia pronta para que eu possa me basear e evite cometer erros de design?

Não existe uma solução única para todos os casos, mas eu recomendaria dar uma olhada no [Princípio da Inversão de Dependência](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), e seus padrões relacionados (em particular a [Injeção de Dependência](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_depend%C3%AAncia) e a [Inversão de Controle](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invers%C3%A3o_de_controle), dentre outros). O ponto chave é habilitar seu sistema a receber extensões sem ter que recompilá-lo, ou melhor ainda sem nem ter que *parar* o mesmo ao acrescentar/remover um plugin (mais difícil, porém muito útil durante o desenvolvimento e também cômodo para o usuário final).

Por fim, se você já possui um sistema pronto e percebe a necessidade de customizá-lo (seja com plugins, seja de alguma outra forma), muitas vezes pode ser necessário refatorá-lo, de modo a **abstrair** a interface entre os componentes (ex.: a forma como seu sistema se comunica com a biblioteca A) e posteriormente **realizar** essa abstração através de duas implementações concretas (uma que comunica com A, outra que comunica com B). Nesse caso, a inversão de dependência pode ajudar, mas não é necessário seguir todo o caminho até tornar seu sistema "plugável" para colher os benefícios dessa abstração (pode manter tudo interno mesmo, só com uma linha nas configurações indicando qual [estratégia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy) seguir).